# Import CSV file (contains some non-UTF8 characters) in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, csv, utf-8, data-import, database

How can I import a CSV file that contains some non-UTF8 characters to MongoDB? 
I tried a recommended importing code.

```
mongoimport --db dbname --collection colname --type csv --headerline --file D:/fastfood.xls
```

**Error Message**

```
exception: Invalid UTF8  character detected
```

I would remove those invalid characters manually, but the size of the data is considerably big.

Tried Google with no success.

PS: mongo -v = 2.4.6

Thanks.

**Edit:**
BTW, I'm on Win7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux you could use the `iconv` command as suggested in: [How to remove non UTF-8 characters from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999651/how-to-remove-non-utf-8-characters-from-text-file)

`iconv -f utf8 -t utf8 -c file.txt`

I'm not familiar with MongoDB, so I have no insight on how to preserve the invalid characters during import.

Comment: is that possible on Win too? if i write 'iconv' on CMD, it is not working. (iconv is not recognized as an internal or external command)

Comment: I think the iconv command can be downloaded for windows here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gettext/

Comment: How we can remove invalid UTF-8 characters from .csv file in windows?

Comment: iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 files_with_non_utf8_chars.csv > out.csv

Answer (score 1):

For emacs users: 
Open CSV file in emacs and change encoding using ‘C-x C-m f’ and choosing utf-8 as the coding system. For more information see [ChangingEncodings](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ChangingEncodings)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import an `xls` file as a `csv` file. Save the file as `csv` first, then try again.

Comment: Did you get the desired result (successful import) or the same UTF-8 error? How did you convert the file from xls to csv?

Comment: i mean i got the same results - error. i just saved the file as "csv". didn't used any tool or something to convert it.

Comment: Assuming it's now a valid csv file (e.g. you can see the data when you open the file something like Notepad++) then you do have some weird unicode problems in there. You'll need to pre-process the file before you can load it into Mongo. I would do this using Python; I'm not aware of a direct way to do it with PowerShell.

Comment: Just because it has the .xls suffix doesn't mean it's an excel file.  Plenty of apps output csv/tsv and give it that suffix.  Look at it in notepad.