# CLI option to give encoding format to 'mongoimport '

Tags: mongodb, encoding, import

Does `mongoimport` cli command support only UTF-8 format files?

Is there a way to provide encoding format so that, it can accept non-utf-8 files, without we manually converting each file to UTF-8?

Answer (score 4):

This is one way of doing it on Linux/Unix. You could use `iconv` to convert non-utf8 to utf8 and then use mongoimport on the converted file:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 myfile.csv > myfileutf8.csv
```

`man iconv` should give you more details about options

Also, [Import CSV file (contains some non-UTF8 characters) in MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253581/import-csv-file-contains-some-non-utf8-characters-in-mongodb)
discusses some options for windows.

Comment: Thank You. I was looking to avoid this manual step, if 'mongoimport' has direct encoding option