# Updating Rails App for "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, utf-8

I've been getting this issue with seeding my mongodb application (I'm taking over for a previous developer): `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

Based on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999651/how-to-remove-non-utf-8-characters-from-text-file), I'm using the below command. I'm trying to figure out how I can recursively find all `.rb` files and update them, but the command below isn't work:

`iconv -f utf8 -t utf8 -c /Users/gorefi/Development/gorefi/gorefi/app/controller/*.rb`

Comment: What's not working? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: I was running this through command line on a Mac. I wanted to use the command at the bottom to scan through a folder, updating each file ending in .rb and replace any characters that weren't utf8. I ended up doing each file individually.

Comment: That command should have worked. Did it not?

Comment: Nope, that's why I posted it. Was wondering if my syntax was correct?

Comment: Worked on OSX for me, FWIW.