# Remove all non utf-8 characters from file with no output in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, utf-8, output

I am a new Ubuntu user dealing with a very large file with a few non-utf8 characters that can be safely skipped. I found another stack overflow question [How to remove non UTF-8 characters from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999651/how-to-remove-non-utf-8-characters-from-text-file) that gave a way to remove those characters, using the command

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c file.txt
```

however with the size of my file, this outputs every line, which takes too much time. I'm not too familiar with Ubuntu commands so if anyone could guide me on modifying that command to suppress outputs, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output the conversion to a new file using shell redirection:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c file.txt > new-file.txt
```

Then check the end of new file:

```
tail new-file.txt
```

Check the top:

```
head new-file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output to a new file, instead of printing every line on the terminal:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c file.txt > output.txt
```