# How to find Invalid UTF-8 Character in oracle column

Tags: java, xml, oracle, encoding, utf-8

I have oracle table in which I am storing XML file , column is of CLOB type . Then we picked  that xml file for further processing . It is somewhere breaking with below exception

"com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0 (at char #931, byte #20)"

When we copy the content in notepad++ ,it didn't show any invalid UTF-8 Character.

Could any one help how to find invalid UTF-8 character in XML file in oracle column , request you to considering column is of CLOB type.

ANy help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to Unix? You can use `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c yourfile.xml`. You can find more possible options in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999651/how-to-remove-non-utf-8-characters-from-text-file).

Comment: No I am using oracle client in window , do not have unix access