# pandoc complains about utf-8 decoding error even if my file is valid utf-8 encoded file

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, pandoc

I am trying to convert a markdown file to pdf using `pandoc` on Windows system. Since my markdown contains Chinese characters, I use the following command to produce the pdf:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V CJKmainfont=KaiTi test.md -o test.pdfbut
```

But pandoc complains that the file contains non-utf8 characters that it can not handle, the exact error message is:

> Error producing PDF.
>   ! Undefined control sequence.
>   pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xae': >Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.streamDecodeUtf8With: Invalid UTF-8 stream

According to what I have find in the internet. This is largely due to the encoding of the markdown file and may have nothing to do with pandoc. My file contains a lot of chinese characters and English characters. I have converted it to utf-8 encoding.

### Things I have tried but without success

#### Grep for the non-utf8 character

Following the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465612/how-to-detect-invalid-utf8-unicode-binary-in-a-text-file) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/filtering-invalid-utf8). I have verified that the system locale is set to UTF-8, output of `localectl status` is:

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
```

I tried to grep for non-utf8 character. Command used is `grep -axv '.*' test.md`. But the command output nothing. (I thought that means there are no invalid characters which can not be decoded by utf-8.)

#### Try to discard invalid characters

I followed the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999651/how-to-remove-non-utf-8-characters-from-text-file) trying to remove non-utf8 characters from my file. The command I use is:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c test.md > output.md
```

After that, When I tried to convert `output.md` to pdf using `pandoc`. I still met the same error message, which suggests that the file still contains non-utf8 characters.

### My question

How can I pinpoint which part of file is causing the problem or how to **really** remove the non-utf8 character from the file so that I can compile it with error?

### Other information

- You can find the markdown file [here](https://github.com/jdhao/setting_backup/blob/master/test.md).
- If you are using Linux system, you may need to set `CJKmainfont` to other valid Chinese font name in your system.

Comment: `grep $´\xbd' test.md` should show you the offending line(s). If they are very long, this is also a lesson in why to wrap your lines.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions. This might be suitable for our sister site [su] (but check their guidelines, and look for duplicate questions).

Comment: Possible dupliacate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465612/how-to-detect-invalid-utf8-unicode-binary-in-a-text-file

Comment: @tripleee the command you give does not work.

Comment: Could depend on locale etc. `perl -ne 'print if /\xbd/' test.md` maybe then; but really, try the commands in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: I had this issue and found that it was due to my .md file being too long. What a useless error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by using backslashes in markdown without escaping. Pandoc treat backslash followed by text in markdown as LaTeX command. Using the following command to generate pdf:

```
pandoc -f markdown-raw_tex --pdf-engine=xelatex -V CJKmainfont=KaiTi test.md -o test.pdf
```

Then the error disappeared and the pdf file can be generated successfully.

### Follow-ups

Thanks to the guru in tex.stackexchange, the cause has been finally found. Essentially, it is xelatex which will produce invalid utf-8 sequence if it encounters invalid control sequence during its processing of tex files. For more information, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413067/pandoc-continues-complain-about-non-utf8-character-even-though-it-seems-there-is/413212#413212) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407744/producing-pdf-from-markdown-with-pandoc-and-xelatex-generate-misleading-error-me).

**update 2017.12.29**
 With the [release of Pandoc 2.0.6](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.0.6), this behaviour is handled more properly:

> Allow lenient decoding of latex error logs, which are not always properly UTF8-encoded

Now, it is easier to debug this kind of issues.